# (beginner) what does expected ";" mean here?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

So this is what I am dealing with:

```
System.out.println("Hey dude, welcome to " The World ".");
```

And i get:

```
prog.java:3: error: ';' expected
```

Other than adding the `\` escape to fix it I don't know what this error means?

can someone explain?

Answer (score 3):

You must use escape character `'\"'` for use " in String.
Example:

```
System.out.println("Hello \"World\"");
```

Print: Hello "World"

Comment: Or use [curly-quotes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Curved_quotes_within_and_across_applications) within your string: `String ex = "Example “curly-quotes”." ;`

Answer (score 1):

To actually explain...
Your error means that the system (compiler) did expect the line to end after

```
"Hey dude, welcome to "
```

or rather, did not expect the line to continue with

```
The World
```

Because *The World* is neither a variable nor method name it can use, you get this synthax error.
What it did expect to get was something like the others have posted before.
Another example using yours...

```
String welcomeTo = "The World";
System.out.println("Hey dude, welcome to " + welcomeTo + ".");
```

Keep going, we all started there.